# fedex shipping web service, test account authentication failed

Tags: web-services, authentication, fedex

can't understand why the credentials of my fedex web services test account won't work for the create shipping service and work for the track package service.
any ideas?

Comment: I have an idea: ask FedEx? :)

Comment: @Thorarin FedEx doesn't answer email most of the time or it takes weeks of answer. I think nico knew it ;)

Comment: Hey, did you get it fixed. I think I am also having the same issue. I applied for test account but they sent me "Developer Test Key", "Test Account Number" and "Test Meter Number" but didn't send me the password. Also I got no email.

Comment: @qasimzee One of the required four keys/meters is only displayed right at the point where you create a test key.

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to differences in test and production wdsl.  You'll see something like this

```
<service name="RateService">
    <port name="RateServicePort" binding="ns:RateServiceSoapBinding">
      <s1:address location="https://gatewaybeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Test is gatewaybeta.fedex.com production is gateway.fedex.com

Edit: Fixed spelling

Comment: The dev domain in the example code is missing an "e" and should be gatewaybeta.fedex.com

Answer (score 1):

**Fedex is giving out bogus credentials.**

I know this post is from 2010, but it appears Fedex has not gotten their act together regarding their test credentials. I was told by someone in Web services tech support that there is a limited array of test credentials and there are some that are simply *not valid*. Turns out, once you get test credentials with your user account, they will always be the same when requested from that account.

*They advised me to create a new fedex.com account and request new credentials.* Fortunately, these were different than the first and worked as soon as I replaced them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while back and it turned out as I recall that I was registered for testing some services and not others.  You may have to call FedEx and have them take a look at your dev account and see what services you are registered for testing.